# Webscraping issue with cloudscraper and proxies

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxies

I have problem with usage proxies servers with cloudscraper.

Simple program:

```
proxy_list = {"http": "http://username:password@ip.my.proxy:port"}
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
print(scraper.get("https://api.ipify.org/", proxies=proxy_list))
exit()
```

This simple program always showing my IP address not used proxy server. Why? I try multiple (working) proxy servers, no errors when running, and always not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I change:

```
proxy_list = {"http": "http://username:password@ip.my.proxy:port"}
to
proxy_list = {"https": "http://username:password@ip.my.proxy:port"}
```

and all now working fine, but I don know why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set proxy for both http and https

```
proxy_list = {"http": "http://username:password@ip.my.proxy:port", "https": "http://username:password@ip.my.proxy:port"}
```